# Oracle join with recursive

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, join

I hava a employee table and department table.

I want to write a query that list employee_ids if its dep_id's status column has 'A'.

For example:

for employee_id = 1, I should see 1 because its parent dept_id(10) has status = 'A'

for employee_id = 2, I should see 2 because its parent dept_id(200) has status = 'A'

for employee_id = 5 ,I should not 5 because its parents do not have status = 'A'

```
Department Table

employee_id | dept_id     | status |level
1           |10           | null   | 1
2           |20           | null   | 1
10          |100          | A      | 2
20          |200          | null   | 2
100         |1000         | null   | 3
200         |2000         | A      | 3
450         |750          | null   | 1
5           |30           | null   | 1
30          |300          | null   | 2
3           |400          | A      | 1
400         |4000         | null   | 2

Employee Table

employee_id | employee_name
1           |  steven
2           |  jone
3           |  eric
4           |  mark
5           |  harry
```

Example Result for above two table is :

```
  | employee_id|
      1
      2
```

My query is like that now :

```
  SELECT Employee.employee_id FROM Department
  JOIN Employee ON Employee.employee_id = Department.employee_id;
```

Comment: AFAIK it's a simply appending `WHERE Department.status = 'A'`

Comment: it gives also 3 but its parent departmens does not contain 'A'.Criterion is parent depatmants should contains 'A'.The query should check parent departmants

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't realized the recursive join over dept_id = employee_id, as @Tejash did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need hiearchy query as follows:

```
SQL> -- SAMPLE DATA
SQL> WITH DEPT_EMP (employee_id , dept_id, status, lVL) as
  2  (select 1   , 10  ,  null, 1 from dual union all
  3  select 2   , 20  ,  null, 1 from dual union all
  4  select 10  , 100 ,  'A'   , 2 from dual union all
  5  select 20  , 200 ,  null, 2 from dual union all
  6  select 100 , 1000,  null, 3 from dual union all
  7  select 200 , 2000, 'A'   , 3 from dual union all
  8  select 450 , 750 ,  null, 1 from dual union all
  9  select 5   , 30  ,  null, 1 from dual union all
 10  select 30  , 300 ,  null, 2 from dual union all
 11  select 3   , 400 ,  'A'   , 1 from dual union all
 12  select 400 , 4000,  null, 2 from dual),
 13  EMPS (employee_id, employee_name) AS
 14  (SELECT 1, 'steven' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 15  SELECT 2, 'jone'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 16  SELECT 3, 'eric'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 17  SELECT 4, 'mark'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 18  SELECT 5, 'harry'  FROM DUAL)
 19  -- YOUR QUERY STARTS FROM HERE
 20  SELECT D.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.EMPLOYEE_NAME
 21    FROM (SELECT STATUS, LVL, CONNECT_BY_ROOT EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMPLOYEE_ID
 22    FROM DEPT_EMP
 23  CONNECT BY  EMPLOYEE_id = PRIOR dept_id) D
 24    JOIN EMPS E ON D.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
 25   WHERE STATUS = 'A' AND LVL > 1;

EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOY
----------- ------
          1 steven
          2 jone

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi @tom, can you please explain to me how is this a good answer ? When I remove the condition: AND LVL > 1 the query returns 3 results. In your question there is no mention of the level column and that it should be larger than 1 ? Tejash - same question for you too. Here is the fiddle where you can see that it returns 3 rows : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1983646668aba1bb2458b91722361f7f my answer returns 2 rows. Thanks. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.employee_id, E.EMPLOYEE_NAME
FROM Employee E
JOIN department D ON E.employee_id = D.employee_id
join department T on D.dept_id = T.employee_id
where T.status = 'A'
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46b5441b37bf371eb977c9fb4f5680fa)